# How to wait for angular requests to complete for automation testing

Tags: angular, selenium

I am facing issues while automating Spartacus angular application using selenium java. Selenium is not waiting for all angular requests to complete. As the request takes a few seconds to generate, selenium thinks the page has loaded successfully. but there is still process going on in background.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you haven't yet, you need to make an honest attempt at solving the problem yourself before asking here. If you've tried something already that didn't work, share that as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and ask a specific question about the problem you ran into.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of waiting you want there are multiple ways to reach your goal.
This [link](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/selenium-wait-for-page-to-load) will provide you an overview alongside some code.

Comment: This works with normal Java application but not with angular applications.

Answer (score 0):

[I hop it help you](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.browserstack.com/guide/wait-commands-in-selenium-webdriver&ved=2ahUKEwjJ48CYqsr3AhXEu6QKHVXUBjIQFnoECBIQBQ&usg=AOvVaw1wsicstQzxH59gZ9OA8bWP)

I dont know you are using selenium on which language
You can search "how to wait for load an element in selenium"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This works with normal Java application but not with angular applications.